# GitLab integration with Bugzilla in year 2020

Tags: gitlab, bugzilla

I tried to configure GitLab integration with Bugzilla but without success. Can somebody provide an example of:

- Project url (e.g. http://bugzilla/describecomponents.cgi?product=MY_PROD&component=MY_COMP)
- Issues url (e.g. http://bugzilla/buglist.cgi?id=:id)
- New issue url (http://bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=MY_PROD&component=MY_COMP)?

I tried to provide that, but I cannot see any changes in neither GitLab nor Bugzilla.

How references in commit should look like? GitLab documentation states in [one place](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.8/ee/integration/external-issue-tracker.html) that it should be CODE-123, where code is some unknown tracker identifier, while in [another place](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/bugzilla.html) they state it should be #123.

What functionality should I expect? Will it just provide a reference from commit to issue, or will it also add a reference to Bugzilla and maybe resolve/assign bugs?